Is this true: $\left| \|A\|_{\infty} \|x\|_{\infty} - \|B\|_{\infty} \|y\|_{\infty} \right| \leq \|Ax + By\|_{\infty}$?
I am trying to lower bound the following norm in the Euclidean space
\begin{align}
\left \|Ax + By \right\|_{\infty},
\end{align}
where $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^n$.
I made an attempt, but I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly. Please correct me if I am wrong.
We can start with the definitions and properties:

For any vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$, the infinity norm is defined as:
\begin{align}
  \|v\|_{\infty} = \max_{i} |v_i|
  \end{align}
For a matrix $M \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, the induced infinity norm is defined as:
\begin{align}
  \|M\|_{\infty} = \max_{i} \sum_{j} |M_{ij}|
  \end{align}
For any matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ and vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, we have the property:
\begin{align}
  \|Ax\|_{\infty} \leq \|A\|_{\infty} \|x\|_{\infty}
  \end{align}
and similarly,
\begin{align}
  \|By\|_{\infty} \leq \|B\|_{\infty} \|y\|_{\infty}
  \end{align}

The reverse triangle inequality for the infinity norm states:
\begin{align}
\|u + v\|_{\infty} \geq \left| \|u\|_{\infty} - \|v\|_{\infty} \right|
\end{align}
Applying this to $u = Ax$ and $v = By$, we get:
\begin{align}
\|Ax + By\|_{\infty} \geq \left| \|Ax\|_{\infty} - \|By\|_{\infty} \right|
\end{align}
To find the lower bound, we need to understand how $\|Ax\|_{\infty}$ and $\|By\|_{\infty}$ relate to $\|A\|_{\infty}$ and $\|B\|_{\infty}$.
By the sub-multiplicative property of matrix norms, we have:
\begin{align}
\|Ax\|_{\infty} \leq \|A\|_{\infty} \|x\|_{\infty}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\|By\|_{\infty} \leq \|B\|_{\infty} \|y\|_{\infty}
\end{align}
Thus, we can write:
\begin{align}
\|Ax + By\|_{\infty} \geq \left| \|A\|_{\infty} \|x\|_{\infty} - \|B\|_{\infty} \|y\|_{\infty} \right|
\end{align}
Combining these results, we can get the following bound for $\|Ax + By\|_{\infty}$:
\begin{align}
\boxed{\left| \|A\|_{\infty} \|x\|_{\infty} - \|B\|_{\infty} \|y\|_{\infty} \right| \leq \left|  \|x\|_{\infty} - \|y\|_{\infty} \right| \leq \|Ax + By\|_{\infty}},
\end{align}
where I assumed that $\|A\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ and $\|B\|_{\infty} \leq 1$.

I think the line which needs another look is "Thus, we can write: ..."

@AlexOrtiz Please enlighten me

As an "example" of why it fails, if $0\le x \le X$ and $0 \le y \le Y$, then why should it be the case that $|x-y|\ge |X-Y|$? It won't in general because I can make $|X-Y|$ bigger than $|x-y|$ by as much as I like. Say $x = 3, y= 2$, $X = 100$, $Y = 50$.

@AlexOrtiz Correct. Apparently, this lower bound is wrong. Can we find a better and correct non-zero lower bound?

This cannot be correct. The right hand side could be zero while the left hand side can be any positive number.
More concretely choose a matrix $B$ and a vector $y$ such that $ 0 < \|By\|_\infty < \|B\|_\infty \|y\|_\infty$. Then set $x = - By$ and $A = I$. The left hand side is positive while the right hand side is zero.

You are right. Do you have a suggestion to find a better lower bound?

Without further assumptions on $A$ and $B$, the best lower bound is obviously $0$.

No this is not true. Take $A$ the orthogonal projection onto some proper subspace. Thus $\|A\|_\infty=1$. Now choose $y=0$ and $x$ a norm $1$ element orthogonal to this subspace. The LHS is thus $1$, but the RHS is $0$.
